# Как сделать редирект для админ панели?

Tags: php

Делаю ре-директ для админ панели.
Задача : если человек попробует вести в адресную строку путь к админ панели, то его перебросит на форму авторизации. Возникли трудности

Создал файл functions.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = false;

function connectDB() {
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Hunter");
}

function checkUser($login) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE 'login'='$login' AND 'password'='$password'");
    $row = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
    closeDB();
    if ($result_set->fetch_assoc()) return true;
    else return false;

}
function isAdmin($login) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE 'login'='$login'");
    $row = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
    closeDB();
    return $row["ident"];

}
function closeDB() {
    global $mysqli;
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Таблица admin имеет 4 поля : id, login, password, ident. indent - просто нейки идентификатор(единица)

В верху формы авторизации пишу:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "lib/functions.php";
if (checkUser($_SESSION["login"], $_SESSION["password"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Инициализация сессии > подкл файла function.php > условие (если администратор уже авторизован, перекинуть на админ панель). Ну и снизу форма входа

Для самой админ панели создаю файл start.php , пишу :

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "/lib/functions.php";
if (!((checkUser($_SESSION["login"], $_SESSION["password"])) && 
(isAdmin($_SESSION["login"])))) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Подкл файла functions.php > условие на отрицание > редирект на форму авторизации

Ну и на самой админ панели подключаю файл start.php.

Редирект проходит, если я попытаюсь вести путь к админ панели > перебросит на форму авторизации. Но вот когда ввожу данные ( логин и пароль), то форма просто обновляется, или же редирект происходит. Помогите доработать код, указать на ошибки. Очень нужна помощь!

Comment: А где вы определяете $_SESSION?

Comment: @Finies вопросы, на который я не знаю ответ :) Я не до конца понял, как правильно работает сессия :(

Comment: по сути $_SESSION - это глобальная переменная хранящаяся на сервере и обновляющаяся только тогда, когда скрипт обновляет её явным образом. Тем более в $_SESSION не имеет смысл (да и по хорошему просто нельзя) хранить пароль в открытом виде (его вообще нигде нельзя хранить в открытом виде - используйте хэш и сравнивайте хэши паролей).

Answer (score 1):

Более подробно раскрою суть своих комментариев в ответе.

Ваша форма должна передовать данные методом POST (на мой взгляд для авторизации он предпочтителен) или GET. Метод указывается в виде атрибута тэга `form`, вот так:

```
<FORM method="post">
```

Скрипт php получает данные такой формы в глобальную системную переменную $_POST, которая является ассоциированным массивом. Т.е. если вам нужно получить значение элементы формы с именем скажем name1, например `<INPUT type="text" name="name1">`, то в php-скрипте, она будет получена как `$_POST['name1']`.

Т.е. ваша функция авторизации в упрощённом должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
function checkUser($login, $password) { //тут не забудьте добавить второй параметр, иначе функция переменную $password не увидит
    global $mysqli;
    $result_set = $mysqli->query ("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE 'login'='$login' AND 'password'='$password'");
    if($result_set->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $result_set->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['UserID'] = $row['id'] //Определяем переменную сессии с id пользователя
        $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'] //Определяем системную переменную с логином пользователя
        $auth = true;
    } else
        $auth = false;
    return $auth;
}
```

Тогда в форме авторизации у вас должно быть:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "lib/functions.php";

// хотя вот тут по хорошему нужно встроить проверку на то, что $_POST["login"] вообще существует, т.к. он появится только после отправки формы

if (checkUser($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

А в самой админке:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "/lib/functions.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION["login"]) || ($_SESSION['UserID']>0) == false) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Как то так, но по хорошему нужно ещё встроить проверку получаемых значений, а не передавать их напрямую в базу + как я говорил в комментариях, в базе хранить не пароль в открытом виде, а его хэш, соответственно и в функцию проверки передавать хэш пароля.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно сделать редирект, лучше использовать настройки .htaccess файла. Для примера:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^adminpanel https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```